# Enum in Javascript

Tags: javascript, enums, modular

In Javascript I'm going to read data (`strData`). But the data are String values, but I have to work with Integer values.

For example:

```
intData = strData;
```

...where `strData` could be "A", "B", or "C".

But `intData` should be 1 for "A", 2 for "B", or 3 for "C".

I could just do an If-else statement, but I have to get `strData` very often. In this case, I always have to "if-else" the content of `strData`. So I need something to keep the code as short as possible. An one-time allocation of the Integer values to the String values. How I have to impelement that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`intData = ({ A: 1, B: 2, C: 3})[strData]`

For example (transcript from Chrome debugger console):

```
>  (function() { var strData = "C"; return ({ A: 1, B: 2, C: 3})[strData]; })()
<- 3
```

Comment: Ok, but it's not like this?... intData = ({ "A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 3})strData;

Comment: Can be either. Property labels in JavaScript object literals can be quoted or not. Try it!

Comment: It works exactly as you have written above. But I had to use "" for A, B, and C. Thank you David and have a nice day :-)

Comment: I'm glad that was helpful. I couldn't tell what you meant about the double quotes. I'm updating my answer with an example I used from the Chrome debugger: does my syntax not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [Object.Freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) with plain object:

```
var ENUM = Object.freeze({a: 1});
ENUM['a'];
```